# DiMarzio Bass Pickups

Tags: bass-guitar, pick-ups

I was planning on upgrading my bass pickups with a set of DiMarzio DP123, they have however 4 wires per pickup. Could anyone please tell me, which wires need to be connected where in the following diagram, such that the pickup's output goes into the red lead, and the ground goes into the grey lead.
The pickup wires are in the DiMarzio colorscheme (The diagram includes a series/parallel switch, a blend pot and a double tone pot).

[image: DiMarzio in the bass diagram]

Comment: Is the diagram what you actually have in your instrument, and if so do you want to use the series/parallel switch?  The DiMarzio pickups come with a small instruction pamphlet that shows different wiring configurations. IIRC, you connect the black and white together for standard humbucking output.

Comment: Yes this is exactly how the bass is wired, I do not have the pickups yet, so that is why I posted the question. So that means black and white together, red to red and green to grey?

Comment: What bass are you wiring these too? Assuming those pots are 1 volume and 1 tone? https://www.dimarzio.com/support/wiring-diagrams

Comment: It is a Chapman MLB1 FF DH, I redid the wiring to add the series/parallel switch and the double tone switch. So according to the diagram, I could simply solder white and black together, red as the pickup's output, and green to ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what the commentors have said is true, solder white and black together, red as the pickup's output and green to ground.
I have update the diagram:
[image]